# eBay API setting Child Categories Doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I'm asking here and not on eBay forums because no one seems to ever respond or is active there.

Basically I'm using the SetStoreCategories method on the Trading API.
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/SetStoreCategories.html

My data part of the API call is as follows

```
<Action>Add</Action>
<StoreCategories>
  <CustomCategory>
     <Name>name of a thing</Name>
     <ChildCategory>
        <Name>a child name</Name>
     </ChildCategory>
  </CustomCategory>
  <CustomCategory>
     <Name>name of another thing</Name>
     <ChildCategory>
        <Name>2nd child name</Name>
     </ChildCategory>
  </CustomCategory>
```

And the eBay API result is

```
array(7) {
  ["Timestamp"]=>
  string(24) "2013-07-15T01:49:39.888Z"
  ["Ack"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["Version"]=>
  string(3) "831"
  ["Build"]=>
  string(32) "E831_CORE_APISELLING_16205050_R1"
  ["TaskID"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Status"]=>
  string(8) "Complete"
  ["CustomCategory"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["CustomCategory"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["CategoryID"]=>
        string(9) "660835819"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(15) "name of a thing"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["CategoryID"]=>
        string(9) "660835919"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(21) "name of another thing"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you can see that it's not looking at my child categories. I've check on ebay.com and they aren't there.

The ebay api says that a CustomCategory element is the same type as a ChildCategory type. And you can only nest 3 children in. But I can't even get 1 to nest.

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you can't do this. You have to make 1 level call at a time, getting back the categoryIds then setting DestinationParentCategoryID in the subsequent calls.